# error getting data procedure in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I created a stored procedure, which saves values ​​in a table temporal.y then I show with the "select " but only in my sqlserver works well . when you call the procedure in codeigniter I generated an empty array.

THIS IS MY PROCEDURE IN CODEIGNITER

```
function verificacion_ocupados($codigo,$llave_maestra){
    $sql = "sp_verificacionocupados ?, ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql,array($codigo, $llave_maestra)); 
    $data = $query->result();
    $query->free_result();           

    return $data; 
}
```

THIS IS MY PROCEDURE

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_verificacionocupados]
@codigo int,
@llave_maestro varchar(50)
   AS
   DECLARE @finicio date;
   DECLARE @ffinal date;
   DECLARE @codigo_dias int;
   DECLARE @no VARCHAR(100);
   create table #pivote(
    code int 
   );
    SET @no='veremos';
   BEGIN
       SELECT @ffinal=Oel_Fecha_Fin,@finicio=Oel_Fecha_Inicio 
       FROM Operaciones_Especiales_Llave
       where Em_Codigo=@codigo and Oel_Estado=2 and Th_Llave=@llave_maestro ;
          IF @@ROWCOUNT>0
           BEGIN         
                  INSERT INTO #pivote VALUES (2);       
          END
    END
     SELECT code from #pivote;
GO
```

This is just one example of a much larger consultation I am doing .
I think the problem is in the temporary table and as I call to return data.

Who has an idea what is the problem ? . Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use profiler to see what actual SQL command is being sent from CodeIgniter to your db.   Maybe the problem is your CodeIgniter is calling sp_verificacionocupadose, but your stored proc is named sp_verificacionocupados2

Comment: You shouldn't use sp_ prefix for stored procedures, it has a special purpose in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

change it as following.

```
   function verificacion_ocupados($codigo,$llave_maestra)
  {
    $sql="sp_verificacionocupadose ?, ?";
    $query=$this->db->query('call sp_verificacionocupadose("$codigo","$llave_maestra")')); 
    $data=$query->result();
    $query->free_result();           
    return $data;
  }
```